# MBProgrssHUD error with Cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, mbprogresshud

Here is the simple code of usage of MBProgressHUD

```
// Add at the top of the file
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"

// Add right before return TRUE in textFieldShouldReturn
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.labelText = @"Redeeming code...";

// Add at start of requestFinished AND requestFailed
[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
```

And obviously we need a view to add the MBProgressHUD into.

The problem is that there is no view in cocos2d, but only CCNode.

So, is there any way to solve this problem?

By adding an UIview onto a CCLayer ?

If this is a stupid question, please accept my apology as I am still very new in programming.

Answer (score 0):

adding an UIView onto a CCLayer cannot be done because they are separate view hierarchies'

you will need to find your toplevel EAGLView (which subclasses UIView) and add the MBProgressHUD as a child of that. Or use a cocos2d menu system.

Or you could port the MBProgressHUD code into cocos2d?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I better try to understand what EAGLView is, as I don't think I could port the MBProgressHUD into cocos2d

Comment: try this: [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] animated:YES];

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you for your kindly help.

Could you suggest me some materials for further investigating or studying on this?

Comment: With recent versions of cocos2d, you can use : [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] animated:YES];